# Run vimscript function only once although v:count1 > 1

Tags: vimscript, functions, filetype-xml

I have a function that accepts a count of iterations, its `command` is defined with `-range`:

```
command -nargs=1 -range DocbkPrintTag :call s:DocbkPrintTag(<f-args>)
```

and to output

```
<listitem>
<para>
</para>
</listitem>
```

I map it followingly:

```
nnoremap <unique> <localleader>li :<C-U>DocbkPrintTag li<CR>
```

the `<listitem>` is defined in a custom dictionary as

```
let s:tags.li = { 'tag': 'listitem', 'type': 'outline', 'include': ['pa'] }
```

while `<para>` ['pa'] is defined as

```
let s:tags.pa = { 'tag': 'para', 'type': 'outline' }
```

The `DocbkPrintTag` function calls another function `DocbkRenderTag` which assembles the XML output for a tag, possibly rendering it n-times if `count` is specified on a keyboard before the mapping itself.
The problem is that for the case of ,
I call `DocbkRenderTag` recursively from itself to first render `<para/>` as an inside element of `<listitem/>`.
Everyhing works fine for 1 repetition, but if i want to print 2 or more such structures, the `v:count1` parameter is passed over to the inner function calling
but the inner tag should be repeated only once. How can i force to do the inner function call only once?

For completeness, here is the important part of the code:

```
if !exists(":DocbkPrintTag")
  command -nargs=1 -range DocbkPrintTag :call s:DocbkPrintTag(<f-args>)
endif

function s:DocbkPrintTag(tag)
  let result = s:DocbkRenderTag(a:tag)
  if !empty(result)
    call feedkeys('a' . result, 'n')
  endif
endfunction

function s:DocbkRenderTag(tag)
  [...]
  let result = ''
  " number of repetitions
  let i = 1
  while i <= v:count1 
    [...]
    if !empty(include)
      for incl_tag in include
        let incl_result .= s:DocbkRenderTag(incl_tag)
      endfor
    endif
    [...]
  endwhile
  return result
endfunction
```

The output now is for example

```
<listitem><para></para><para></para></listitem>
<listitem><para></para><para></para></listitem>
```

instead of just

```
<listitem><para></para></listitem>
<listitem><para></para></listitem>
```

Comment: I think your question would be easier to understand if you gave us a bit more code to understand what you are doing: You could create a minimal example to reproduce your behavior (we don't need the whole tag rendering for example) which would help people to help you.

Comment: Still missing code related to `v:count1`. You should also describe how you invoke your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `<para>` because you apply `v:count1` to every tag you render. Try this:

```
function s:DocbkPrintTag(tag)

  " apply v:count1 to the outside tag
  put =repeat(s:DocbkRenderTag(a:tag), v:count1)
endfunction

function s:DocbkRenderTag(tag)
  ...

  " render single tag here
  if !empty(include)
    for incl_tag in include
      let incl_result .= s:DocbkRenderTag(incl_tag)
    endfor
  endif
  ...
endfunction
```

IMO, raw `command` with [:h :command-completion-customlist](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion-customlist) is way better than `map` here. `v:count1` can be replaced with [:h optional-function-argument](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#optional-function-argument) .

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but: i'm writing a lot of DocBook text, and i need a fast access to render complex DocBook structures. for example, after pressing `,7il` i expect to render whole `<itemizedlist>` with 7 `<listitem><para></para></listitem>` inside. i dont want to call a function, that's too much keypresses for me

Comment: You can create a map like this `nnoremap ,d :DocbkPrintTag<space>`, then you only need to type `,dlistitem 7`, the `listitem` can be completed with `<tab>`.  Did my answer solve the `v:count1 > 1` problem? It feels like you didn't think it did.

Comment: Your proposed way with `repeat()` works perfectly! Thanks!